# Maps - Polyline Change Color Based On Speed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

[image]I have an array of 3 different levels of color with speed ranging between values of

1. less than 60
2. between 60 and 80
3. more than 120.

I can put each lat long in an array where speed is one of the 3 options and use a different color for each however I have noticed that, if I have speed less than 60 as a starting point, for example, and then only have that at the end as well, the less than 60 at the beginning will connect with the less than 60 at the end therefore drawing a straight line, is there a way I can connect polyline based on minimum distance perhaps, even if I use different zoom levels point Y in an array of say less than 60 will connect to point Z (the next point) because it does not know of the other two arrays in between.

```
var myTripGoing60 = [];
for (i = 0; i < latlngdataGoing60.length; i = i + 2) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngdataGoing60[i], latlngdataGoing60[i + 1]);
    myTripGoing60.push(point);
}

var myTripGoing6080 = [];
for (i = 0; i < latlngdataGoing6080.length; i = i + 2) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngdataGoing6080[i], latlngdataGoing6080[i + 1]);
    myTripGoing6080.push(point);
}


var myTripGoing120 = [];
for (i = 0; i < latlngdataGoing120.length; i = i + 2) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngdataGoing120[i], latlngdataGoing120[i + 1]);
    myTripGoing120.push(point);
}


var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: myTripGoing60,
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 7
});
flightPath.setMap(map);

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: myTripGoing6080,
    strokeColor: "#99FF00",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 7
});
flightPath.setMap(map);

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: myTripGoing120,
    strokeColor: "#003300",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 7
});
flightPath.setMap(map);
```

Comment: I don't completely understand.  Is your problem that if you only have two points, you have a straight line between them?  Can you give an example of some data that demonstrates the problem?  Maybe a screenshot showing what's happening versus what you'd like to happen

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: So the order of the points is important. However you've just grouped them into 3 categories without regard to their order. Presumably you've also got those points in that order, that you could use to help construct the array of points you'll need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I used Markers (dots) instead of Polyline - It will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to achieve this was:

Go through every coordinate in your array, and grab the current iteration as the starting point of the polyline and the current iteration + 1 for the end point of that polyline, you can put the colour you want for that line.

Then you move to the next one, and so on, repeat this process for every coordinate you have in your array.

[image]